# With the Charge plugin, can you add an additional one-off fee on subscription?

Tags: plugin-charge

Is there a way to add an additional one off fee using Charge plugin? Example situation: I need to charge my subscriber $150 USD per month.  However, for the first month only, there is an additional $50 USD for the set-up fee.